# How can I import a component based on the current url?

Tags: gatsby

I'd like to import different CSS depending on which page I'm on. The HTML will stay the same. What do I need to do to access the current location?

I was thinking I could put an `if` statement in the constructor and import the CSS there, but I'm not sure that will work.

EDIT: you can't import from within the `constructor`, so is there a way to do a conditional import?

Here's my code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'


class Menu extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        //how do I get myCurrentLocation?
        if(myCurrentLocation == '/') {
            import menuStyle from '../page-assets/global/styles/menu/_home-page.sass'
        } else {
            import menuStyle from '../page-assets/global/styles/menu/_regular-page.sass'
        }
    }

    render (){
        return (
            <nav className="menu">
                <Link to="/work-ive-done/" className="menu-item">
                    <span className="menu-item__heading">
                        Work
                    </span>
                    <span className="menu-item__sub-text">
                        ive done
                    </span>
                </Link>

                //other menu items ...

            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Are you looking for window.location?

Comment: @StephenCrosby window.location would work, but I thought there might be a React property for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gatsby-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-link) is a wrapper for react-router-dom Link, so you should be able to access your route by using `this.props.match.path`.

otherwise: 
You can access your current url using `window.location.href`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: This is helpful! I'll see if I can access that `this.props.match.path`

Comment: I'm not able to access `this.props.match.path` in the `render()` or `constructor()` functions. Should it be available in that scope?

Comment: Where are you rendering your menu component? If it is within a route component, then you can pass those props down to menu.

Comment: Ah, duh, that was it. Sorry, my React is pretty rusty!

Comment: Turns out `this.props.location.pathname` was the ticket. `this.props.match.path` seemed to only have `/` in it regardless of the page I was on. But I'm using Gatsby's default router where it makes routes out of whatever pages you have in the `pages` directory, so maybe it doesn't populate `this.props.match.path`.

Answer (score 1):

In Gatsby v2, the page components will be able to access their location through the following:

- for `class` components: `this.props.location.pathname`
- for `functional` components: `props.location.pathname`

For function components, ensure `props` are being passed through their params. e.g.

```
const IndexPage = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <p>This works {props.location.pathname}</p>
  </Layout>
)
```

For anywhere else, you can use `@reach/router`'s `Location` component (credits: [jlengstorf](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1875#issuecomment-420811319))

```
import React from 'react';
import { Location } from '@reach/router';

export default () => (
  <Location>
    {({ navigate, location }) => /* ... */}
  </Location>
);
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/v82ol26w9l) showing the above. Also credits [jlengstorf](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8787#issuecomment-427216043) .

Comment: props.location.pathname works well in development, but in production, once I push to github pages, it works well just on the first load. After the service workers starts, it doesn't work anymore. But it's very weird, cause if I output the value, it does return it... I'm baffled.

Comment: @JoanMira I'd file an issue for this behavior. They're definitely helpful and would be interested in this behavior.