# In Gatsby how to identify if current page being rendered is 404?

Tags: url, path, gatsby, custom-error-pages

In `src/pages` I've setup a *404.js* page per the docs "[Adding a 404 Page](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/adding-common-features/add-404-page/)". Within this file I'm calling my `Layout` component and also passing in `location` props.

In my *Layout.js* file I'm trying to conditionally render some components based on wether the current page is a `404`. In my testing the location object doesn't render a boolean for this, example testing with the browser `asdsada`:

```
hash: ""
host: "localhost:8000"
hostname: "localhost"
href: "http://localhost:8000/asdsada"
key: "initial"
origin: "http://localhost:8000"
pathname: "/asdsada"
port: "8000"
protocol: "http:"
search: ""
state: null
```

I was unable to find a way to do this after reading:

- [How to get pathname in the layout file in gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631403/how-to-get-pathname-in-the-layout-file-in-gatsby)
- [Get Target Path in Gatsby [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64546846/get-target-path-in-gatsby)
- [How to get the current url within a React / Gatsby Class Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69854547/how-to-get-the-current-url-within-a-react-gatsby-class-component)
- [Gatsby Link pass previous page's location.path to next page via Props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381325/gatsby-link-pass-previous-pages-location-path-to-next-page-via-props)
- [How can I import a component based on the current url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102024/how-can-i-import-a-component-based-on-the-current-url)
- [Displaying The URL On a 404 Page In Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105698/displaying-the-url-on-a-404-page-in-gatsby)

In Gatsby is there a way to identify if the current page being rendered is the 404 page so I can ternary a component?

Comment: This issue is also discussed [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5045). The solutions on this page didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a boolean in your `src/pages/404.js` to your `Layout` like:

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

const NotFoundPage = () => (
  <Layout is404Page={true}>
    <div>Your Content</div>
  </Layout>
)

export default NotFoundPage
```

Comment: talk about over complicating things 

Comment: This doesn't work if you're using 'gatsby-plugin-layout' to keep layout elements from unmounting and remounting between page transitions, because you don't get to manally nest each page content between the layout component.